# Do I use "or" or "nor" in this instance?

Tags: word-usage

Should I say "No termites rust or rot"?
Or should it be "No termites rust NOR rot"?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Termites neither rust nor rot."

or

"No termites either rust or rot."

LATER:  But see the much more plausible interpetation by @Cascabel in the comments which follow.

Comment: I think the OP wanted "No termites, rust, or rot."

Comment: That's a plausible variant I didn't think of.  You should re-post it as an answer and get proper credit for it!  (Decontextualized statements are a pain to decode.) Isn't there a biblical reference behind it somewhere?

Comment: Matthew 6:19: "Lay not up for yourselves treasures upon earth, where moth and rust doth corrupt, and where thieves break through and steal." (KJV). Close, but not a bull.

Comment: I rather think it is an advertisement for a house? apartment? gardening supplies? Who can tell without better context.

Comment: Spot on!  I've now upticked both your comments.  You're clearly correct in your inference.  I really ought to delete my answer, but I'll leave it as is, with your corrections.

Comment: No worries. It is gonna close soon anyway, for off-topic due to unclear and lack of context.

Comment: Robin, if a question is not posed well, connoisseurs of this site prefer that you contribute a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @aparente001 I did ponder this at the time, but finally plumped for Answer rather than Comment.  I'll keep this in mind for the future. (I think one factor was Comments are a pain to format.)  Ta! RH